# Twig accessing array values using variables

Tags: twig

```
{% set key = 'something' %}
```

My `array` has key something, I and can it access `array['something']`, but when I try to use variable in key like:

```
array[key]
```

I'm getting error that array key not exist. So question is how to access array keys using variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [attribute](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/attribute.html) function:

```
{{ attribute(array, key) }}
```

From the doc:

> addition, the defined test can check for the existence of a dynamic
> attribute:
>
> ```
> {{ attribute(object, method) is defined ? 'Method exists' : 'Method does not exist' }}
> ```

Hope this help

Comment: URL is not working anymore here's the new link to the documentation [attribute](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/attribute.html)

Comment: Thanks @Thezeus I've updated the link